# How to resolve version conflicts between nuget packages

Tags: collections, version, nuget-package, coreclr

I'm using an ASP.NET Core application in which I have a dependency on two conflicting nuget packages. Package restore output displays the conflict as follows:

```
Version conflict detected for System.Collections.
MyProject (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.Localization (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0) -> System.Linq (>= 4.1.0) -> System.Collections (>= 4.0.11)
MyProject (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-x64 (>= 1.0.0) -> System.Collections (= 4.0.10).
```

When I use the pre-release version of CoreCLR-x64, I get another conflict on System.Collections:

```
Version conflict detected for System.Collections.
 MyProject (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.Localization (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 1.0.0) -> System.Linq (>= 4.1.0) -> System.Collections (>= 4.0.11)
 MyProject (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-x64 (>= 1.0.1-beta-23225) -> System.Collections (= 4.0.11-beta-23225).
```

Slightly more puzzling to me, since the top dependency should be able to accept a later version than 4.0.11...

When I use an earlier version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, I need to change the versions of more than 10 other dependencies. Is this the only way? Can this be done in a better way than manually?

How to deal with problems like this, specifically and generally?

Comment: I think this is just a warning. Can't you ignore it? Also, why do you directly depend on `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-x64`?